# Google analytics Plot Rows

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

It is possible to pull the data from google analytics plot rows using javascript?
This is my Google analytics data [My Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmIZe.png)

And this is my chart [My Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVgmE.png) that pulling the pageviews. But i dont know how to pull the plot rows data using javascript.

This is My code for my chart:

```
$scope.chart1 = {
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            metrics: 'ga:pageviews',
            dimensions: 'ga:date',
            'start-date': '7daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'today',
        },
        chart: {
            container: 'chart1', 
            type: 'LINE',
            options: {
                width: '770',
                height: '300',
                legend: 
                    {
                        position: 'top', alignment: 'center',
                        textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 13}
                    },
                colors: ['blue', 'orange', 'red'],
                animation:
                   {
                       "startup": true,
                       duration: 1500,
                       easing: 'out'
                   }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this. I can only seem to get one value between the date ranges and not a 'per day' value.